# How to keep data in component when using v-with in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So here is my problem:

I want to make a component that takes it's values from v-with="values" and add them to my component model after some modification, then display those modified properties.

But from what I understand, when I set values with "v-with", component data are erased so the binding between my component data (not v-with one) and my directives are lost.

I'm really new to this framework, I don't see any solution, so I guess it was time to ask my first question here !

Here is the HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">
    <p v-on="click:reloadParentMsg">Msg parent : {{ParentMsg}}</p>
    <p v-on="click:reloadChildMsg">Msg child  : {{ChildMsg}}</p>
</script>

<div id="myVue">
    <my-component v-with="ParentData" ></my-component>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '#my-template',
  data: function () {
      return {
          ChildMsg: "wololo"
      }
  },
  methods:{
      reloadParentMsg : function(){
          this.ParentMsg="Parent";
          console.log(this.ParentMsg);
      },
      reloadChildMsg : function(){
          this.ChildMsg="Child";
          console.log(this.ChildMsg);
      }
  }
})

var myVue = new Vue({
    el: '#myVue',
    data: {
        ParentData:{ParentMsg: "gloubiboulga"}
    }
})
```

And the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KwakawK/hfj1tv4n/3/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, but I believe it can be solved by using the second form of `v-with`, which is `v-with="childProp: parentProp"`. Rather than the parent property overriding all of the child data, this will replace only the property on the left of the colon.

So I think your code can be fixed by changing the v-with to this:

`<my-component v-with="ParentMsg: ParentData.ParentMsg" ></my-component>`

Here's the updated code as a snippet:

```js
// register the grid component
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '#my-template',
  data: function () {
    return {
      ChildMsg: "wololo"
    }
  },
  methods:{
      reloadParentMsg : function(){
          this.ParentMsg="Parent";
          console.log(this.ParentMsg);
      },
      reloadChildMsg : function(){
          this.ChildMsg="Child";
          console.log(this.ChildMsg);
      }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var myVue = new Vue({
  el: '#myVue',
  data: {
      ParentData:{ParentMsg: "gloubiboulga"}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.11.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">
    <p v-on="click:reloadParentMsg">Msg parent : {{ParentMsg}}</p>
    <p v-on="click:reloadChildMsg">Msg child  : {{ChildMsg}}</p>
</script>

<div id="myVue">
  <my-component v-with="ParentMsg: ParentData.ParentMsg" ></my-component>
</div>
```

See the [Vue guide](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing_Down_Individual_Properties) for more information.